# exponential integral equation with different low bound

Tags: python

For my below exponential integral equation, I have lower bound starting from a value instead of negative infinite. so it is different from scipy.expi function. I am finding a post below using sympy and make some modification, hope you can help me confirm it. Thanks

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.expi.html

Integration of exponential function in Python

```
from scipy import integrate
import sympy
import numpy as np

S = lambda z: np.exp(-z)/z
print(integrate.quad(S, u, np.inf))
```

[image]

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: is my code correct? I'd like to confirm it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's another exponential integral function, `exp1` in the [documentation.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.exp1.html) But yes, your code was correct, as this simple test shows:

```py
>>> from scipy import integrate
>>> from scipy.special import exp1
>>> import numpy as np
>>> integrate.quad(lambda x: np.exp(-x) / x, 1, np.inf)
(0.21938393439551238, 3.816771238185377e-10)
>>> exp1(1)
0.21938393439552062
```

Comment: Wow blorgon, you made my day. Glad to know the other function of exp1, I really appreciate your help. You help me solve my problem. Have a great day, blorgon!